Error in cloud function pulling firestore fields for push notification
I am trying to send push notifications using cloud functions and I am sending these push notifications to users in my firestore database based on stored info in the database such as token and notification time.
Please help, I am getting an error.
Error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at beforeSnapshotConstructor (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v1/providers/firestore.js:109:93)
    at changeConstructor (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v1/providers/firestore.js:113:40)
    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/v1/cloud-functions.js:80:34)
    at /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:98:17
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)

This is my cloud function code.
exports.scheduleNotifications = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const newData = change.after.data();
    const oldData = change.before.data();

    console.log('New data:', newData);
    console.log('Old data:', oldData);

    // Check if newData and oldData exist and are objects
    if (!newData || !oldData || typeof newData !== 'object' || typeof oldData !== 'object') {
      console.log('Invalid data format. Exiting function.');
      return null; // Exit function if data is missing or not in expected format
    }

    // Get notificationTime from newData and oldData
    const newNotificationTime = newData.notificationTime;
    const oldNotificationTime = oldData.notificationTime;

    // Check if notificationTime has been updated
    if (newNotificationTime !== oldNotificationTime) {
      console.log('Notification time updated. New time:', newNotificationTime);

      // Validate notificationTime format
      if (typeof newNotificationTime === 'string' && newNotificationTime.includes(':')) {
        // Parse notificationTime string into Date object
        const [hours, minutes] = newNotificationTime.split(':');
        const scheduledTime = new Date();
        scheduledTime.setHours(parseInt(hours, 10));
        scheduledTime.setMinutes(parseInt(minutes, 10));
        scheduledTime.setSeconds(0);
        scheduledTime.setMilliseconds(0);

        console.log('Scheduled time:', scheduledTime);

        const currentTime = new Date();
        console.log('Current time:', currentTime);

        // Compare current time with scheduled time
        if (currentTime >= scheduledTime) {
          // Send FCM notification
          const message = {
            notification: {
              title: 'Your Daily Affirmation',
              body: 'This is your scheduled notification message.',
            },
            token: newData.fcmToken, // Use the FCM token from the user document
          };

          console.log('Sending FCM message:', message);

          await admin.messaging().send(message);
          console.log('Scheduled notification sent successfully to user:', context.params.userId);
        } else {
          console.log('Scheduled notification is not yet due for user:', context.params.userId);
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Invalid or missing notificationTime format:', newNotificationTime);
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Notification time has not changed.');
    }
  });

Thanks much!
What I have tried -- error still persists with minimal code.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = admin.firestore();

exports.scheduleNotifications = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {   });


Which line of code causes the error?  Please edit the question with more debugging details, including the results of your logging that help indicate where the problem is.

it is happening in the very first line of code functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}')
.onCreate(async (change, context) and then the function crashes.

How did you reach that conclusion?  That line doesn't actually "run" when the function is invoked - it just defines the function for deployment.

well I removed all code after that line, and the same error persists.

OK, that's what you should be showing in your question - the minimal code that reproduces the error, along with the steps you take to cause the error.  Please edit the question to include these details.  We should be able to duplicate the problem using the information and steps you provide.

okay thanks! I made that edit.

You're still missing the steps you take to cause the error.  We should be able to duplicate the problem using the information and steps you provide.

my firestore structure has fcmToken(string), notificationTime(string)
and all I did was run the code above and that is the error I got.

Right, you need to tell us how exactly you ran this code so we can duplicate the behavior.  Please edit the question to include these details. As your question stands now, it's going to get closed for lack of debugging details

sorry not sure what other details to add? This is in my index.js code this is all the code I have const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const firestore = admin.firestore();
exports.scheduleNotifications = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userId}')
.onUpdate(async (change, context) => {   });

my only thinking is that somehow it is not recognizing the firestore document
